# WiFi stopped working unless I modify the nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: wifi, pop-os

My WiFi stopped working and I tried changing `nameserver 127.0.0.53` to `nameserver 1.1.1.1` in `/etc/resolv.conf`, and now it sort of works. I can use Firefox, but apps like Spotify and Discord don't load. I can ping fine in cmd.

Obviously this isn't a permanent fix, partially since it doesn't fix everything, and also `/etc/resolv.conf` reloads every time I restart.

I also noticed when typing a command `sudo ...`, it says "sudo: unable to resolve host thinkpad: Name or service not known" where "thinkpad" is the name of my device.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I think it stopped working a couple of days ago after my ProtonVPN GUI client wouldn't connect, perhaps that caused it somehow

Comment: Please be careful of your terminology. You say that your WiFi doesn't work but it seems that you actually mean your DNS isn't working. Very different things

Comment: I would rather suspect that it's the other way around: The DNS problem is causing the VPN problem. The "unable to resolve host thinkpad" makes sense. This is a hostname not known by external dnsservers. (And by using 1.1.1.1 you are trying to use a external one directly)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume your distro is using systemd (most do).

- Restore `/etc/resolv.conf`
- Check if `systemd-resolve` is running with `systemctl status systemd-resolved`
- If it's not: Restart it with `systemctl restart systemd-resolved` *(actually... it never hurts to restart it anyway)*
- Check if you are using the DNS-servers your ISP tells you to use with: `systemd-resolve --status | grep "DNS Server"`

Comment: Running `systemctl status systemd-resolved` gives:

Feb 22 18:20:55 thinkpad systemd-resolved[624]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server ::1.

Comment: And `systemd-resolve --status | grep "DNS Server" gives: Current DNS Server: ::1
       DNS Servers: ::1